# use '&' to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++

Error   C3867   'Class::pervaia': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
Не могу понять место, куда я должна поставить &
Я понимаю ,что в строчке

```
otv = func(pervaia, a);
```

функция pervaia должна иметь передаваемое значение в (), когда у меня была написана эта же программа, но не разделенная на классы, то все работало.
Буду очень благодарна за помощь.

1.сpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Class.h"
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

class MyClass : public Class {
public:
double pervaia(double x)
    {
        return pow(x, 4) + pow(x, 3);
    }
};

int main()
{    
    double  a, b;
    MyClass l;
    cout << "Input the interval: " << '\n';
    cout << "a=";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "b=";
    cin >> b;
    cout << '\n';
    cout << "MIN: " << l.neww(a, b) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Class.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Class.h"
using namespace std;
double Class::func(ykaz y, double x)
{
    double deltaX = 0.0000001;
    return (((this->*y)(x + deltaX) - (this->*y)(x)) / deltaX);
    }
    double Class::neww(double a, double b) {
    double deltaX = 0.0000001;
    double otv, min, otvv, otvvv, x, aa, c;

    otv = func(pervaia, a);
    otvv = func(pervaia, a + deltaX);
    otvvv = (otvv - otv) / deltaX;
    min = otvvv;
    aa = a;

    for (int i = 0; i <= b - a; i++)
    {
        x = aa;
        cout << "x=" << x << '\t';
        otv = func(pervaia, x);
        otvv = func(pervaia, x + deltaX);

        otvvv = (otvv - otv) / deltaX;
        cout << otvvv << endl;

        if (min > otvvv)
        {
            min = otvvv;
        }
        aa++;
    }
    return min;
}
```

Class.h

```
#ifndef Class_h
#define Class_h
class Class
{
public:
    typedef double(Class::*ykaz)(double);
    double func(ykaz y, double);
    double neww(double a, double b);
    virtual double pervaia(double x)=0;
};
#endif
```

Comment: а почему не    Moiclass  а MyClass ?..

Comment: первое, что пришло в голову

Comment: я это к тому, что вы  часто создаете  русские  имена

Comment: когда вы все это написали не создавая классы, то вы не могли писать  typedef double(Class::*ykaz)(double); поэтому у вас не было ошибки компиляции

Comment: Да, там было просто  typedef double(*ykaz)(double);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызывайте вот так

```
otv = func(&Class::pervaia, a);
```

Comment: ну и какое это имеет отношение с кодом автора?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan поправил

Comment: если использовать ваш вариант, то пропадает ошибка о &, но появляется другая: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: virtual double __thiscall Class::pervaia(double)

Comment: @ИринаЛактионова да, точно. У вас ведь метод Class::prevaia не реализован, так что и вызвать его не получиться. Но можно будет вызвать MyClass::pervaia

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, но все у меня норм. Я проверила, добавила  #include "Class.cpp" и выскочили ошибки, что уже определено в 1.cpp

Comment: @ИринаЛактионова я исправил комментарий, посмотрите его

Comment: @Asem,  все дело в том, что она вызывает функцию в  функции   double Class::func(ykaz y, double x), т.е.  вызов и так  в области видимости  Class,   т.е.  достаточно и &pervaia

Comment: если вы имеете ввиду так  otv = func(&MyClass::pervaia, a), то ничего не выходит, куча ошибок

Comment: @ARHovsepyan  ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function. Не знаю чем обусловлен такой запрет, но он есть.

Comment: @ИринаЛактионова для того чтобы вызвать вот так otv = func(&MyClass::pervaia, a) вам прийдеться либо разбить класс MyClass на header и реализацию и подключить MyClass.h к Сlass.cpp или перенести содержимое Class.cpp в 1.cpp.

Comment: я сделал отдельно еще доп h и cpp файлы, подключила, но ничего этим не добилась, все еще куча ошибок

Comment: @ИринаЛактионова вот ссылка на архив с проектом, все собирается. http://transfiles.ru/puxbz

Comment: Asem, да, это так и есть _ я ошибся

Answer (score 2):

Вы определили указатель на функцию член класса прямо в классе

```
 typedef double(Class::*ykaz)(double);
```

и функцию

```
double func(ykaz y, double);
```

т.е. в аргументе функции должен быть не указатель на функцию, а указатель на функцию-член

а потом вызываете

```
func(pervaia, a);
```

компилятор не видит ожидаемый указатель на функцию-член, потому что вы передаете просто указатель на функцию `pervaia`

или вызывайте так

```
func(&Class::pervaia, a);  (зависит от вашего кода, будет ли это правильно)
```

или же перепешите в классе обявление

```
class Class
{
public:
   typedef  double (*ykaz)(double);
...
};
```

чтоб `ykaz` был типом указателья на функцию, а  не указателем на функцию-член

Comment: второй вариант мне не подходит, я обязательно должна тут использовать typedef

Comment: а первый вариант я тоже пробовала ,но мне вылазит ошибка:'&': illegal operation on bound member function expression

Comment: Ну да, конкретно в  вашем случаи первый вариант не подходит, а я невнимателен был при просмотре кода,  но сейчас исправил ответ.  Вернее я ваш код и не читал особо, поскольку ошибка очевидна

Comment: в этом и состоит моя проблема, что и & нельзя поставить и typedef нельзя убрать

Comment: пробовала другой вариант, я делала функцию  pervaia не virtual, a static
тогда будет  typedef double(*ykaz)(double); и  return (((y)(x + deltaX) - (y)(x)) / deltaX);

Comment: Почитайте конец в измененном виде

Comment: Да там виртуальность функции в вашем коде вообше не имеет смысла  и даже неправильна, потому что  в дочерном классе функция имеет другие аргументы